# Solving and Plotting Differential Equation using DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have got a differntial equation which I have tried to solve with DSolve

```
sol = DSolve[p'[t] - (2 p[t]^2) - 3 p[t] + 4 p[t]^-9 == 0, p, t]
```

The answer implies RootSum. The question is how to use and plot the solution. I have tried

```
Plot[Evaluate[p[t] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {t, -7, 7}]
```

which doesn't work. Moreover, this case is not documented in the documentation "Plotting the Solution".

Need help; Thanks

Comment: Do you necessarily need an analytical solution ? It may be best to go for NDSolve.

Comment: When using `NDSolve[]` it appears that for any initial condition, the system quickly reaches a singularity.

Comment: @Feyre: Not when I tried to solve it in the range {0,7}

Comment: I am getting some kind of solution and also a plot of it but I am unable to make anything out if it specifically the cone like shape in the plot, `NDSolve[{p'[t] - (2 p[t]^2) - 3 p[t] + 4 p[t]^-9 == 0, 
  p'[0] == 2}, p, {t, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @Feyre and @Lotus, The plot code I have used is `Plot[Evaluate[p[t] /. %], {t, 0, 10}]` but I am unable to make anything out if it specifically the cone like shape in the plot.

Comment: @SudiptaSen That code has a singularity at `t~0.318`. `Plot[p[t] /. %, {t, 0, 0.317}]` does work.

Comment: @Feyre Thanks, got it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `RootSum` but `Solve`:

```
sol = DSolve[p'[t] - (2 p[t]^2) - 3 p[t] + 4 p[t]^-9 == 0, p, t]
(*
  Solve[1/2 RootSum[-4 + 3 #1^10 + 2 #1^11 &, 
      Log[p[t] - #1]/(15 + 11 #1) &] == t + C[1], p[t]]
*)
```

Workarounds for plotting include replacing `Solve` with `FindRoot` or `# &`, or replacing the variable to be solved for by `t`:

```
Block[{Solve = fr, fr, t},
 fr[eq_, x_] /; NumericQ[t] :=(*x/.*)FindRoot[eq, {x, 1}];
 Plot[Evaluate@Quiet[p[t] /. (sol /. {C[1] -> 1})], {t, -1.45, -1}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 50}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{Solve = # &, p},
 ContourPlot[sol /. {p[t] -> p, C[1] -> 1} // Evaluate,
  {t, -1.4, -1}, {p, 0, 50}, Exclusions -> None]
 ]

(* plot like that above *)
```

Solving for `t` gives us the inverse function of the solution, which we can plot with `ParametricPlot`:

```
Block[{eq, t},
 eq = Block[{Solve = #1 &}, sol];
 With[{tt = t /. First@Solve[eq /. {C[1] -> 1, p[t] -> p}, t]},
  ParametricPlot[{tt, p}, {p, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.6, Exclusions -> None]
  ]]

(* plot like that above *)
```

---

*Update: Alternatives for visualizing the solutions of a first-order ODE*

One can plot the direction field with [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html).  Here is a utility to construct a direction field.

```
Clear[dirfield];
dirfield[de_, v_, t_] := Module[{y, df},
   y = First@Flatten[{v /. (y1_)[t] :> y1}];
   df = {1, y'[t]} /. Solve[de, y'[t]];
   First[df /. y[t] -> y] /; Length[df] == 1
   ];

Expand@dirfield[p'[t] - (2 p[t]^2) - 3 p[t] + 4 p[t]^-9 == 0, p, t]
(*  {1, -(4/p^9) + 3 p + 2 p^2}  *)
```

Since the OP's ODE is autonomous, it is natural to consider the equilibria.

```
equilibria = NSolve[-(4/p^9) + 3 p + 2 p^2 == 0, Reals]
(*  {{p -> -1.45198}, {p -> -1.21521}, {p -> 0.978767}}  *)
```

There is also a singularity at `p == 0`.  We can incorporate these features into `StreamPlot[]`.

```
StreamPlot[
 dirfield[p'[t] - (2 p[t]^2) - 3 p[t] + 4 p[t]^-9 == 0, p, t],
 {t, -1, 1}, {p, -2, 1.5},
 StreamPoints -> {Join[{{0, p}, Red} /. equilibria, {Automatic}]} // Evaluate,
 GridLines -> {None, {0}}, GridLinesStyle -> Green,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The behavior near `p == 0.978767` can be inferred, but a better picture can be obtained by zooming in.  With `StreamPlot[]`, I would advise keeping the intervals of `t` and `p` approximately equal in length. If you want a much larger range of `t` than `p` or vice versa, I would advise rescaling so that the ranges are about the same.

```
StreamPlot[
 dirfield[p'[t] - (2 p[t]^2) - 3 p[t] + 4 p[t]^-9 == 0, p, t],
 {t, -0.1, 0.1}, {p, 0.9, 1.1},
 StreamPoints -> {{Last[{{0, p}, Red} /. equilibria], Automatic}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am unable to understand the negative values of t, is there a discontinuity issue. I also tried to use the manipulate the plot. I used the following code,`P[t_, a_, b_, c_, d_] = p[t] /.First@NDSolve[{p'[t] - (a*p[t]^2) - b*p[t] + c*(p[t]^(1 - d)) == 0, 
p[0] == 1}, p, {t, 0, 0.335}]; Manipulate[Plot[P[t, a, b, c, d], {t, 0, 0.335}, 
PlotLabel -> P[x, a, b]], {{a, 1, "a"}, -10, 10, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1, "b"}, -5, 5, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c, 1, "c"}, -5, 5, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 1, "d"}, -5, 5, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]` but I am not getting any graph

Comment: @SudiptaSen There does seem to be a discontinuity.  The ODE is autonomous, so I don't see what's not to understand about pos./neg. `t`, except in light of an initial condition.  What condition corresponds to `C[1] -> 1`? -- As for your code, doesn't it give errors?

Comment: @ Michael E2 There maybe a problem with the code, as NDSolve is encountering problem with calculating the derivative at t=0 and I chose the value of C1 arbitarily, anyways I got the solution for this problem. By the way, thanks for showing how to bypass the rootsum issue while plotting.